# org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException in android HttpPost

Tags: android, http-post

Hi i am trying to get data from server by calling HttpPost in my application, it was working fine before but now it's not working(i didn't made any change in code) and giving "org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException" error.

I don't know what can be the problem but after getting error i did searching on google and implemented some additional lines as below but still not getting response getting same error.

```
public static String postRequest(String url, List<NameValuePair> data) {

    String result = "";
    try {

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(HTTP.UTF_8);
        se.setContentType("text/xml");
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

        int timeoutConnection = 10000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                timeoutConnection);

        int timeoutSocket = 10000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);           
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);


        BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpClient
                .execute(httpPost);


        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            result = result.trim();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        return "-333" + e.toString();

    }
    return result;
}
```

it gives me following error:

```
03-19 19:10:17.852: W/System.err(21707): org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
03-19 19:10:17.877: W/System.err(21707):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:750)
03-19 19:10:17.877: W/System.err(21707):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:519)
03-19 19:10:17.882: W/System.err(21707):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:497)
03-19 19:10:17.882: W/System.err(21707):    at com.example.asyntasks.Utility.postRequest(Utility.java:284)
03-19 19:10:17.882: W/System.err(21707):    at com.example.asyntasks.GetHomeItemsTask.getHomeRecipe(GetHomeItemsTask.java:88)
03-19 19:10:17.882: W/System.err(21707):    at com.example.asyntasks.GetHomeItemsTask.doInBackground(GetHomeItemsTask.java:54)
03-19 19:10:17.882: W/System.err(21707):    at com.example.asyntasks.GetHomeItemsTask.doInBackground(GetHomeItemsTask.java:1)
03-19 19:10:17.882: W/System.err(21707):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-19 19:10:17.882: W/System.err(21707):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-19 19:10:17.882: W/System.err(21707):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-19 19:10:17.887: W/System.err(21707):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-19 19:10:17.887: W/System.err(21707):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-19 19:10:17.887: W/System.err(21707):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
03-19 19:10:17.887: W/System.err(21707): Caused by: org.apache.http.client.CircularRedirectException: Circular redirect to 'http://www.example.com/'
03-19 19:10:17.887: W/System.err(21707):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectHandler.getLocationURI(DefaultRedirectHandler.java:173)
03-19 19:10:17.887: W/System.err(21707):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.handleResponse(DefaultRequestDirector.java:932)
03-19 19:10:17.892: W/System.err(21707):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:483)
03-19 19:10:17.892: W/System.err(21707):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:748)
03-19 19:10:17.892: W/System.err(21707):    ... 12 more
03-19 19:10:17.902: W/System.err(21707): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
03-19 19:10:17.902: W/System.err(21707):    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
03-19 19:10:17.902: W/System.err(21707):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
03-19 19:10:17.907: W/System.err(21707):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
03-19 19:10:17.907: W/System.err(21707):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
03-19 19:10:17.907: W/System.err(21707):    at com.example.asyntasks.GetHomeItemsTask.getHomeRecipe(GetHomeItemsTask.java:90)
03-19 19:10:17.907: W/System.err(21707):    at com.example.asyntasks.GetHomeItemsTask.doInBackground(GetHomeItemsTask.java:54)
03-19 19:10:17.907: W/System.err(21707):    at com.example.asyntasks.GetHomeItemsTask.doInBackground(GetHomeItemsTask.java:1)
03-19 19:10:17.907: W/System.err(21707):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-19 19:10:17.907: W/System.err(21707):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-19 19:10:17.907: W/System.err(21707):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-19 19:10:17.907: W/System.err(21707):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-19 19:10:17.927: W/System.err(21707):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-19 19:10:17.927: W/System.err(21707):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

please help me.

Comment: have you checked the URL?

Comment: Is there an exception message?  It's a little harder to test outside of the app when you're posting, but you could use fiddler or some other tool that lets you create HTTP posts and see if the server is still responding like you expect.

Comment: @Mounir Elfassi: yes i checked the url, while i am checking it in postman rest client it gives me response.

Comment: @Mounir Elfassi: yes i checked the url, while i am checking it in postman rest client it gives me response. if i am hosting my web services on other server it works fine, but for my present server it gives me above exception.

Comment: I would think the problem is `Circular redirect to 'http://www.example.com/'`.  No idea what would cause that, and the strange part is if you're hitting the same server from a different client (are you?) and it works fine.